# Why am I getting this message when I try to create an empty project in Sequelize CLI?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I'm getting the error "bash: node_modules/.bin/sequelize: Permission denied" while following the instructions at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html.  This is my first time using Sequelize CLI and I'm fairly new to Linux.  Can someone tell me how to execute the command "node_modules/.bin/sequelize init" without getting this error?  This command is under the Bootstrapping section at the top of the provided link.

I tried sudo and su but that hasn't helped with this situation.  Thanks.  When I try

```
ls -l node_modules/.bin/sequelize
```

I get as output

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1  <account logged in> <account logged in> 30 Jul 19 23:46 node_modules/.bin/sequelize -> ../sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize
```

so I think the file has read, write, and execute permissions for users, groups, and others.

If I try `ls -l sequelize` the output is `ls: cannot access 'sequelize': No such file or directory`.

Comment: No I've learned a bit about commands used for those kinds of questions but it's been a while for me so I don't remember how to use them exactly and not something I've ever had to use in a real situation.

Comment: Please see the last paragraph to the body of my question. It's been updated.

Comment: Ok how can I do that?

Comment: Do `ls  -l node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize`. That is the file that the link points to. Or do as @dsstorefile1 suggests: `ls -lH node_modules/.bin/sequelize`.

Comment: "ls -l node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize" gives me 
"-rw-r--r-- 1  3771 Feb 15 00:33 node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize"

Comment: I tried "chmod 777 node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize" and that gives "-rwxrwxrwx" permissions with the ls -l command.  But when I try "node_modules/.bin/sequelize init" again I now get
"/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory"